# Discord Bot + Google Cloud Run: "Container failed to start."

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, discord.py, google-cloud-run

I'm attempting to deploy a simple Discord bot written in python and containerized via Docker to Google Cloud Run.

The Dockerfile is very simple:

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0

CMD [ "python3", "discord_bot.py"]
```

I can run the bot without issue locally in a Docker container and also pushed it up cleanly to Google Container registry via the cloudmigrate.yaml file below...

```
steps:
  - id: "build image"
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}", "."]

  - id: "push image"
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["push", "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}"]

substitutions:
  _SERVICE_NAME: discord-bot

images:
  - "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}"
```

...but when I attempt to build a Cloud Run instance from the container, I get the issue below:

```
Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information
```

The only issue I have in the logs is the following:

```
We have successfully logged in as <username redacted>

Cloud Rundiscord-bot {@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, resourceName: namespaces/<project name redacted>/services/discord-bot, response: {…}, serviceName: run.googleapis.com, status: {…}}
{@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, resourceName: namespaces/<project name redacted>/services/discord-bot, response: {…}, serviceName: run.googleapis.com, status: {…}}
```

Oddly enough, as shown above, I actually get a message in the logs that the initial login completes successfully, but then it bombs out right after...the python script is a very simple placeholder right now...

```
import os
import discord

TOKEN = os.environ['DISCORD_BOT_LEVEL_TOKEN']

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have successfully logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    #print(message)
    #print(dir(message))

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.lower() == 'hello':
        await message.channel.send(f'Hello, {message.author.display_name}!')
        return

    if message.content.lower() == 'bye':
        await message.channel.send(f'See you later, {message.author.display_name}!')
        return

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Note: I added the environment variable directly on the Cloud Run setup so that's not an issue in this case.

I'm sure it's something simple, but I've been banging my head on this for a couple of hours now...

Comment: client.run create a webservice that listen on the port 8080?

Comment: The container image should be compiled for 64-bit Linux as required by [the container runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#languages). Can you verify if it is compiled for 64-bit Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot run **discord** on Cloud Run as your program does not start an HTTP server that listens on an HTTP port for connections. Your program creates a client that connects to Discord. The Cloud Run health check thinks your container has failed to successfully startup.

In summary, you have a client program connecting to a server (Discord) instead of a server program listening for connections from clients.

You could enable Cloud Run **always-on** CPU allocation and then start two processes. The HTTP Server and the Discord client. However, you will pay for an always running service.

[Run more workloads on Cloud Run with new CPU allocation controls](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-gets-always-on-cpu-allocation)

Comment: Thank you. I ultimately decided to create a client program on compute engine for the exact reason you described here (for those who are curious, I found the video at the link below to be helpful on this front: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QQfdlzqiCE)