# Why GCP Cloud Run shuts down my Discord bot after a minute?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions, google-cloud-run

I have deployed the app from `GitHub` to `GCP Cloud Run` using `GitHub Actions`. After running the application for a minute, `Cloud Run` shuts down my application. I checked my credentials and everything is ok there. How to keep running the application on `Cloud Run`?

I also have provided HTTP client like this:

```js
const requestListener = function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("My cool server!");
};
const app = http.createServer(requestListener);
app.listen(port, () => {
    run(); // RUNS BOT CLIENT
    console.log(`Bot is running. GCP CLoud Run port: ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Can you explain "shuts down the app"? Also have you checked [Discord Bot + Google Cloud Run: "Container failed to start."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70032692/13130697) ?

Comment: Yes, and I have started an HTTP client as well. I will edit my question to provide that code.

Comment: "In Cloud Run, each revision is automatically scaled to the number of container instances needed to handle all incoming requests. When a revision does not receive any traffic, by default it is scaled in to zero container instances. However, if desired, you can change this default to specify an instance to be kept idle or "warm" using the minimum instances setting." See https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling

Comment: @metad00r Thank you, it works. I can mark your answer as the correct one if you'll write that as an answer.

Comment: @dsha256 glad to hear it works for you. I will post the answer right now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"In Cloud Run, each revision is automatically scaled to the number of container instances needed to handle all incoming requests. When a revision does not receive any traffic, by default it is scaled in to zero container instances. However, if desired, you can change this default to specify an instance to be kept idle or "warm" using the minimum instances setting."* See https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling