# Are there any issues having a single server be both a web server and discord (or other) bot?

Tags: web-services, discord, bots, google-cloud-run

Usually bots are hosted on stand-alone (virtual) machines and are always on. For a small personal project, I want to have a bot and a web server: is there any reason they can't be together?  I know that I couldn't "login" as the bot if there were ever multiple instances, but I'm okay limiting the webserver to a single instance (also, it'd be fine if multiple spun up, and only one successfully registered itself as the bot in question).  I would then host this on Cloud Run in GCP where I normally host stuff.

Is this a reasonable setup, or am I inviting some type of issue that I can't foresee?

Comment: A `bot` is just a piece of software. You can run that software on anything that supports its requirements. Your post lacks details and is asking for opinions. Without details on what your bot does, its resource requirements, how it is used, etc how can we answer?

Comment: Ironically, it was your response to a post that lead me to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69977168/discord-bot-google-cloud-run-container-failed-to-start). In it, you say you would have to start two processes. My question here is "why can't it just be the same process?"

Comment: Cloud Run requires that the application start a process that listens for HTTP requests. In my other answer, the bot (discord) does not do that. If your bot provides an HTTP server interface, great. If not you must add one.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was asking then I think; so no problems I should expected associated with this approach then?

Comment: I have no idea what your bot does or requires.

Comment: Under what circumstances would the actions taken by the bot impact its viability to be bundled with a web server running on cloud run?

Comment: Please update your question with details so that it can be answered. Your last comment is too broad. Since you have not provided details on the bot, I do not know what might affect it.